# Importing a text file into SSMS - stop the splitting of a Datetime field into 2 columns

Tags: sql-server, import, ssms

I am using the SSMS import wizard to import a text file (as a flate file). The datetime fields do not come in as expected.

For example, my text file has the following field:

[image]

After import, I get 2 columns:

[image]

How do I get this imported as one column. I have maybe a million rows so looking for a non-manual method

Comment: is your file a Comma Separated or Tab? change to Comma and try again

Comment: Seems like you're trying to import a text file via the Import Flat File wizard in SSMS. Save your data into a (properly encoded) CSV file. _Import Flat File Wizard is a simple way to copy data from a flat file (.csv, .txt) to a new table in your database. The Import Flat File Wizard supports both comma-separated and fixed width format files._ ref: [Import Flat File to SQL Wizard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/import-flat-file-wizard?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(sql13.swb.importflatfile.f1)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=sql-server-ver15)